# Java Mission Control with windows services: disabled functionality

Tags: windows-services, tomcat6, jmc

I am trying to use the "Log historical data" functionality provided by Java Mission Control to record information about:

```
 - Used Java Heap Memory
 - Commited Java Heap
 - Maximum Java Heap
```

of a local tomcat instance running as a Windows service.However I can't add any new graph using the "Add..." button.

It is fine if I try the same with a local application, but some parts of JMC seem to be disabled when connecting to windows services. The Java options that I am using for Tomcat are:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6666
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've already got an answer for your question, but if not, I have some questions for you:

- Which version of JMC are you using?
- Can you run JMC with -consoleLog (JDK\bin\jmc -consoleLog | more), so see if you get any - output?
- Can't you find the MBeans, or what happens when you want to add them to a graph?
- Can you see the MBeans if you connect with jconsole?

//Klara, JMC dev